# What is the RegExpValidator.flags property used for?

Tags: regex, flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, mxml

I'm attempting to write a custom RegExpValidator in AS3 (similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981145/regexpvalidator-never-matches)).  I'm wondering (and I've checked livedocs...), what is the 'flags' property on a RegExpValidator used for?

All of the examples I find set it to "g", what is that all about?  The [livedocs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/validators/RegExpValidator.html#includeExamplesSummary) as well as some StackOverflow questions have the same use `flags = "g"`.

What other values are allowed?  What is the value-add of this property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means match globally.  This is consistent with most regular expression engines.  Otherwise it will only match the first case, so if your regex is to replace the word 'one' with 'two' without 'g', it only does the first match.

Answer (score 4):

You can find a list of flags [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/RegExp.html#RegExp%28%29):

- g — When using the replace() method
  of the String class, specify this
  modifier to replace all matches,
  rather than only the first one. This
  modifier corresponds to the global
  property of the RegExp instance.
- i — The regular expression is
  evaluated without case sensitivity.
  This modifier corresponds to the
  ignoreCase property of the RegExp
  instance.
- s — The dot (.) character matches
  new-line characters. Note This
  modifier corresponds to the dotall
  property of the RegExp instance.
- m — The caret (^) character and
  dollar sign ($) match before and
  after new-line characters. This
  modifier corresponds to the multiline
  property of the RegExp instance.
- x — White space characters in the re
  string are ignored, so that you can
  write more readable constructors.
  This modifier corresponds to the
  extended property of the RegExp
  instance.

Comment: This answer is definitely helpful, it's much appreciated!